# Manually counting the number of character in a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I tried to manually count the number of characters in my string including any blank spaces. I coded this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Unos(char* string, int duzina)
{
    int i=0;
    char c;
    do {
        c=getchar();
        string[i]=c;
        i++;
    } while(c != '\n' && i<duzina);
}

int brojznak(char* str)
{
    int i=0,br=0;
    while(*str++ != '\0')
    {
        br++;
    }
    return br;
}

int main()
{
    char recenica[100];
    printf("Unesite recenicu\n");

    Unos(recenica,100);
    int i=0;

    printf("%d",brojznak(recenica));
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work correctly, but I think it should. On the other hand, if we change condition:

```
int brojznak(char* str)
{
    int i=0,br=0;
    while(*str++ != '\0')
    {
        br++;
    }
    return br;
}
```

It again sometimes prints some random characters, but counts it accurately. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: It doesn't even compile because of this: `printf("%d",brojznak(recenica));`

Comment: What is the correct output for this code that you want?

Comment: And you said: `In the other hand if we change condition`. There is no difference between the first and second implementation of `brojznak()` you posted.

Comment: Where did you defined `recenica` or do you mean  `printf("%d",brojznak("recenica"));`

Comment: The second brojznak is the same as the first one as well, I think you need to fix that.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't copy whol code, recenica is array of characters like    char recenica[100]; i have function that creat this string or array i'll paste whole code...

Comment: @Bosancheros Please update the question with all the relevant code (not just in the comments). Also, please clarify what you mean by "print some random characters". Your `printf` only prints a single integer. So do you mean the integer value printed is sometimes random?

Comment: The given string does not terminate by `'\0'`.

Comment: does that mean that strings usually terminate by  '\0', but not neccesary

Comment: @Bosancheros Please, you really need to provide all the relevant info instead of a little bit each time. Your latest code does not show where you print out the buffer. It only prints the count. There is no way any one can help you if your code does not match the description.

Comment: @Bosancheros `Unos` should be set `0` to end  of the string.

Comment: @ Alan Au... for example if i enter "hello how are you" result of my function is  or `??22`. In the other hand if i change condition  ` while(*str++ != '\0')` with  ` while(*str++ != '\n') ` program print me  ` mkd17`...hope that you understand me...:D...sorry for errors, lapsus mentis, it's very late now...:D, and mate this is whole code, nothing else i have on my laptop...:/

Comment: @  BLUEPIXY it work now, whole problem was that. I had to set 0 at the end of the string...thanks a lot man...:D

Comment: @Bosancheros If it doesn't terminate with '\0' then it's not a string. (That's the definition of a string in C)

Comment: Why do you mean with **manually**.  Do you write code to do things manually?

Comment: @LuisColorado I mean that you create your own function that calculate length of your string. You don't use function like size(), sizeof(),length etc...

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  I misinterpreted you. T count chars, just write `size_t result=0; while (*s++) result++; return result;`  It's so easy to count the chars in a string.

Comment: Yes it is. Problem was that my string didn't have '\0' as a last char. I forgot to terminate my string. Anyway thank man...:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String termination missing in `Unos()`.

`while(*str++ != '\0')` in `brojznak()` does not know when to stop.

```
void Unos(char* string, int duzina) {
  int i=0;
  char c;
  do {
    c = getchar();
    string[i] = c;
    i++;
  } while(c != '\n' && (i + 1) <duzina);  // Insure enough room
  string[i]='\0';  // add this
}
```

Some other refinements:

```
void Unos2(char* string, size_t duzina) {
  size_t i = 0;
  while ((i+1) < duzina) { Only attempt to read if space allows it.
    int c = getchar(); // Use int to distinguish EOF from characters
    if (c == EOF) break;
    string[i] = c;
    i++;
    if (c == '\n') break;
  }
  string[i] = '\0';  // add this
}
```

Comment: Yes. Definitely string termination.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(i=0; getchar()!='\n'; ++i)
       ;
```

Comment: "If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and `getchar` returns `EOF`."  Certainly this answer's code will then loop without end.